# Microsoft Outlook on the Mac App Store - no option for in app purchase

Tags: ms-office, mac-appstore

Microsoft Outlook on the Mac App Store requires an Office 365 subscription. There is supposed to be an option to subscribe using an in app purchase - I want to use this option.

However, the darn thing never gives me any option to do so. I initially tried to activate using an old account, but that account does not have an Office 365 subscription.

[image]

I have tried in vain to remove every trace of Outlook and start over - I've removed the keychain entry for "Office," and removed more or less everything with "Microsoft" in the name in ~/Library (including the obvious stuff in ~/Library/Containers, /Library, and /System/Library. I've removed the application from /Applications as well, emptied the trash, and rebooted.

I have tried clicking "Stay Offline," to open outlook, and then open its list of accounts - there are none. I have also tried using outlooks profile tool to remove the existing profile, to no effect.

But once I install the app from the Mac App Store, the blasted account is still listed. I do not have any other office applications installed.

So, how can I either (a) reset outlook completely so it doesn't show this account (and thus hopefully gives me the option to use an in-app purchase to subscribe, or (b) force outlook to activate using an in-app purchase?

Comment: I hate to say this but what if you create a new account and try it there. The accounts in Outlook are supposed to be local to each user and a different user account might do the trick.

Comment: @SteveChambers, I ended up doing that and it "worked" - launching outlook allowed me to choose "Go Premium" (what I imagine to be the path that leads to allowing an in-app purchase) - and it immediately prompted me for an account! The way outlook uses in-app purchases is totally different from what I expected - you *must* have a Microsoft account. Once you create that account, then you will have the option to use an in app purchase. (I did not have or want such an account - I want to use outlook with an exchange server.)

Comment: @SteveChambers At any rate, that was the kick in the pants I needed - everything is working now. Thank you :)

Comment: @negacao Any chance you would be willing to rewrite your comment into an answer? You can then mark your own answer as accepted and your question will appear as solved, which will help others with a similar issue. Thank you!

Comment: @jaume, I gave it a go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any future readers, the Mac app store version of Outlook simply does not work the way I expected. You will not be given the option to subscribe using an in-app purchase until after you have created or logged in with a Microsoft account.

Once you have logged in with a Microsoft account, then will you have the option to subscribe using an in-app purchase.